# How to change textformfield spacing?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I am new to using flutter. I want to ask. How to change the spacing between textformfield? I have done the same as textformfield address, Postcode and District for textformfield firstname, last name, and relationship but still not successful. I have changed the container margin and padding and used spacing wrap for textformfield firstname, last name and relationship but still not successful. Where is my coding error? Please, someone, help me in solving this problem.

This is my code:

```
Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      //margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 10, vertical: 40),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 210),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                      /*decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                              /* top: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                width: 2.0,
                              ),*/
                              bottom: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0))),*/
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 30,
                            child: Text(
                              'Next of kin 1',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                              //height: 51,
                              //width: 30,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              //margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                              /*padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),*/
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    color: Colors.transparent,
                                    width: 1.0,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Wrap(
                                      direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                      alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                                      //spacing: 20.0,
                                      children: [
                                        Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 30,
                                              child: Text(
                                                'First Name',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.bold,
                                                    fontSize: 16),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              width: 300,
                                              //height: 100,
                                              child: TextFormField(
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black),
                                                controller:
                                                    nextOfKinFirstName,
                                                onSaved: (String? value) {
                                                  nextOfKinFirstName.text =
                                                      value!;
                                                },
                                                decoration:
                                                    const InputDecoration(
                                                  border:
                                                      OutlineInputBorder(),
                                                  hintText: 'First Name',
                                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                      fontSize: 16),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                      child: Wrap(
                                    children: [
                                      Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 30,
                                            child: Text(
                                              'Last Name',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight:
                                                      FontWeight.bold,
                                                  fontSize: 16),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 300,
                                            //height: 100,
                                            child: TextFormField(
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black),
                                              controller: nextOfKinLastName,
                                              onSaved: (String? value) {
                                                nextOfKinLastName.text =
                                                    value!;
                                              },
                                              decoration:
                                                  const InputDecoration(
                                                border:
                                                    OutlineInputBorder(),
                                                hintText: 'Last Name',
                                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black,
                                                    fontSize: 16),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 30,
                                          child: Text(
                                            'Relationship',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 16),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                          height: 51,
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              border: Border.all(
                                                color: Colors.black12,
                                                width: 1.0,
                                              ),
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                              width: 300,
                                              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                                underline: Container(
                                                    color:
                                                        Colors.transparent),
                                                hint: _nextOfKinRelationship ==
                                                        null
                                                    ? Text('Relationship')
                                                    : Text(
                                                        _nextOfKinRelationship),
                                                isExpanded: true,
                                                value:
                                                    _nextOfKinRelationship,
                                                items: <String>[
                                                  'Father',
                                                  'Mother',
                                                  'Husband',
                                                  'Wife',
                                                  'Son',
                                                  'Daughter',
                                                  'Brother',
                                                  'Sister',
                                                  'Grandfather',
                                                  'Grandmother',
                                                  'Grandson',
                                                  'Grandaughter',
                                                  'Uncle',
                                                  'Aunt',
                                                  'Cousin',
                                                  'Nephew',
                                                  'Neice',
                                                  'Father in law',
                                                  'Mother in law',
                                                  'Son in law',
                                                  'Daughter in law',
                                                  'Brother in law',
                                                  'Sister in law',
                                                  'Friend'
                                                ].map((String value) {
                                                  return new DropdownMenuItem<
                                                      String>(
                                                    value: value,
                                                    child: new Text(value),
                                                  );
                                                }).toList(),
                                                onChanged: (value) {
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    _nextOfKinRelationship =
                                                        value!;
                                                  });
                                                },
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: i think it cause by  `Expanded` Widget.   The children inside your `Row` widget will devide space into 3 and fit the widget child

Comment: Do I have to remove the expanded?

Comment: im not sure, it will caused error if you put `TextField` inside the `Row`  without `Expanded`

Comment: why you use `Wrap` , i think  you can remove it, just use `Column` is enough

Comment: I try to move the *Wrap* widget but still the same.

Comment: i know the issue, 
i will put in answer column

Comment: Ok sure. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you use `Row` to cover 3 `TextField` and wrap it with `expanded`, the space that available will be devide into 3.

but for the `TextField` you wrap it with certain width (`SizedBox`). and i think current screen is wider than all children inside `Row`

my suggestion is change it with `Container` which is fit available space.

```
Row(
children: [
// option 1
  Expanded(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text("label"),
        TextField(), // without sizebox ,
      ],
    ),
  ),
//option 2
  Expanded(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text("label"),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity, // push to maximum space available
          child: TextField(),
        ) // use container insted  if you want to make decoration ,
      ],
    ),
  ),
],
);
```

Comment: i just try it on  https://dartpad.dev/ 
everything is ok